# useRef to detect isVisible is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add animation to my react div when I scroll and reach the area. I want it to fade in, but the problem is the `useEffect` to detect the scroll part is not working and I don't know what is wrong with it. Can you guys help me with this?

Here's the code:

My useEffect

```
    useEffect(() => {
      const handleScroll = () => {
        const element = aboutEncotekiRef.current;
        console.log('element', element);
        if (element) {
          const { top, bottom } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
          const isVisible = top < window.innerHeight && bottom >= 0;
          setIsVisible(isVisible);
          console.log('hello world');
        }
      };
  
      window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      };
    }, []);
```

My div

```
<div className={`aboutEncoteki ${isVisible ? 'fade-in' : ''}`} ref={aboutEncotekiRef}>
    <Row className='mb-3' lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
        <h1 className = 'FontGothamRoundedBold'>
             Try me
        </h1>
    </Row>
</div>
```

Comment: I think dependency array [] should be removed from useEffect as it is not dependent in any variable

Comment: Can you give more information. Do logs execute on scroll? What does it log for element? What is the value of isVisible on each scroll?

Comment: the logs didn't execute at all

Comment: Are you able to create a [mre] so we can see the issue for ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Just as @nuser137 mentioned, you should remove the dependency array. Your `useEffect` executes only once.</s>

See: https://css-tricks.com/run-useeffect-only-once/

Updated answer:

I have been playing with your code in here:

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/aeh95/pen/oNaJqpN)

It looks like it is working as expected.

UPDATE 2:
As suggested in our discussion in the chat, for performance you can use the Intersection Observer API and this code.

From the debugging, seems like there's a wrapper (parent element) around your element that has the scroll and not the window.

Code for Interesection Observer API below:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const handleScroll = (entries) => {
    const isVisible = entries[0].isIntersecting;
    setIsVisible(isVisible);
  };

  const options = {
    root: null, // Use the viewport as the root
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.01, // Adjust the threshold as needed
  };

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleScroll, options);
  const target = aboutEncotekiRef.current;

  if (target) {
    observer.observe(target);
  }

  return () => {
    if (target) {
      observer.unobserve(target);
    }
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Why does the `useEffect` need to re-execute on every rerender though? OPs code should work even if it executes once on load since it's adding a scroll event listener which will be executed multiple times (and the event handler has no closures over outside variables that could cause stale references), so I don't see how this will change much?

Comment: That's actually a fair observation there. I'm wondering if OP is actually using useRef to create the ref?

Comment: Yeah, not sure, I've asked them to create a reproducible example so we can see in more detail what's going on, but we'll have to wait and see :)

Comment: I've added a CodePen using the OPs bits. Just a basic App. It seems like it should work if ref is assigned correctly.

Comment: Is there any changes that you made to the code ?

Comment: @KimSan the only thing is that I assigned the ref using `useRef`. How are you doing that? See the snippet.

Comment: I'm also using the useRef and I already checked between my code and yours its really similiar

```
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
    const aboutEncotekiRef = useRef(null);
```

I think the problem is in the handle scroll, because it didn't console.log anything

Comment: I would try to debug this. Throw in logs to check if `useEffect` is executed, then check if the `handleScroll` is executed - before defining the element variable and so on til you find what's causing the error?

Comment: I tried to console.log inside the handleScroll but none of them were printed. but if I put it at the same level as the handleScroll function it will get printed twice. I think there's something wrong with the handleScroll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253771/discussion-between-kim-san-and-arnold-haidu).

Answer (score 0):

Effects are triggered when the dependency array items changes, so you need to save the scrollTop in a state and add to the array dep of the effect, with this when scroll changes the effect is executed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example that works fine. I am not sure what exact problem you were facing but this JS Fiddle works.

https://jsfiddle.net/Bro3Simon/neuhq3ba/9/

```
function App() {

const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(false);

const aboutEncotekiRef= React.useRef();

React.useEffect(() => {
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const element = aboutEncotekiRef.current;

    if (element) {
      const { top, bottom } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      const isVisible = top < window.innerHeight && bottom >= 0;

      setIsVisible(isVisible);
    }
  };
  
  console.log("I ran on first render only!");
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  };
}, []);
    
return (
<>
  <div  style={{backgroundColor: isVisible ? "red": "yellow", height: "200vh"}}>{`Is The Second Element Visible : ${isVisible}`}</div>
  
  <div className={`aboutEncoteki ${isVisible ? 'fade-in' : ''}`} ref={aboutEncotekiRef} >
    {`Is Element Visible : ${isVisible}`}
  </div>
</>
  );
}
```